# How do I get the right output from the struct? After loading info from a binary file

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct, malloc

I am trying to read data from a binary file into an inode struct. To represent a file system. However I get a segmentation fault, and do not know how to fix it. I have printed the addresses both inside the load_inodes function and inside debug_fs. My question is, how do I change load_inodes so that the rest of the code will work? My guess was I had to use malloc add the data to the heap to get it right. Or maybe there is something wrong with the entries, hence the address of child outputs as 0x1

The binary file looks like this:

```
00000000: 0000 0000 0200 0000 2f00 0100 0000 0000  ......../.......
00000010: 0200 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 0200 0000  ................
00000020: 0000 0000 0100 0000 0700 0000 6b65 726e  ............kern
00000030: 656c 0000 0120 4e00 0005 0000 0000 0000  el... N.........
00000040: 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0002 0000  ................
00000050: 0000 0000 0003 0000 0000 0000 0004 0000  ................
00000060: 0000 0000 0002 0000 0004 0000 0065 7463  .............etc
00000070: 0001 0000 0000 0001 0000 0003 0000 0000  ................
00000080: 0000 0003 0000 0006 0000 0068 6f73 7473  ...........hosts
00000090: 0000 01c8 0000 0001 0000 0005 0000 0000  ................
000000a0: 0000 00
```

The first four bytes are its id. the next four is the length of the name. The next bytes is the name. The next two bytes are is_directory and is_readonly. The next four is filesize. And next four is entries.

The relevant part of inode.c looks like this:

```
struct inode* load_inodes()  /* this one works on the first inode loadexample1 */
{
    printf("Start of load_inodes()");
    
    FILE* f = fopen("master_file_table", "rb");
    if (f == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open master_file_table for reading\n");
        perror("reason:");
        return NULL;
    }

    printf("NUM_INODES * sizeof: %ld\n\n", NUM_INODES * sizeof(struct inode));
    // Allocate memory for inodes array
    struct inode* inodes = (struct inode*) malloc(NUM_INODES * sizeof(struct inode)+100000);
    printf("ja\n");
    if (inodes == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory for inodes\n");
        fclose(f);
        return NULL;
    }

    printf("Before mainloop\n");

    // Read each inode from the file and store it in the inodes array
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_INODES; i++) {
        uint32_t id;
        fread(&id, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, f);
        inodes[i].id = id;

        printf("ID: %d\n", id);

        uint32_t name_len;
        fread(&name_len, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, f);
        printf("Namelength: %d\n", name_len);

        char* name = (char*) malloc(name_len + 1);
        if (name == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory for inode name\n");
            fclose(f);
            free(inodes);
            return NULL;
        }
        fread(name, sizeof(char), name_len, f);
        name[name_len] = '\0';
        inodes[i].name = name;
        printf("Name: %s\n", name);

        char is_directory;
        fread(&is_directory, sizeof(char), 1, f);
        inodes[i].is_directory = is_directory;
        printf("Is_directory: %d\n", is_directory);

        char is_readonly;
        fread(&is_readonly, sizeof(char), 1, f);
        inodes[i].is_readonly = is_readonly;
        printf("Is_readonly: %d\n", is_readonly);
        
        
        uint32_t filesize;
        fread(&filesize, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, f);
        inodes[i].filesize = filesize;
        printf("Filesize: %d\n", filesize);

        uint32_t num_entries;
        fread(&num_entries, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, f);
        inodes[i].num_entries = num_entries;
        printf("Num_entries: %d\n", num_entries);

        if (num_entries > 0) {
            uintptr_t* entries = (uintptr_t*) malloc(num_entries * sizeof(uintptr_t));
            if (entries == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory for inode entries\n");
                fclose(f);
                free(inodes);
                return NULL;
            }
            fread(entries, sizeof(uintptr_t), num_entries, f);
            inodes[i].entries = entries;
            printf("Entries: %d\n\n", *entries);
        } else {
            inodes[i].entries = NULL;
        }
    }
    printf("Address: %p  Name: %s\n", inodes[0], inodes[0].name);
    printf("Address: %p  Name: %s\n", inodes[1], inodes[1].name);
    printf("Address: %p  Name: %s\n", inodes[2], inodes[2].name);
    printf("Address: %p  Name: %s\n", inodes[3], inodes[3].name);
    // printf("%d\n", inodes[0].is_directory);
    fclose(f);
    // inode_ptr = malloc(10000)
    return inodes;
}





void fs_shutdown( struct inode* inode )
{
}

/* This static variable is used to change the indentation while debug_fs
 * is walking through the tree of inodes and prints information.
 */
static int indent = 0;

void debug_fs( struct inode* node )
{
    printf("Name: %s Address: %p\n", node->name, &node);
    if( node == NULL ) return;
    for( int i=0; i<indent; i++ )
        printf("  ");
    if( node->is_directory )
    {
        printf("%s (id %d) (address: %p\n", node->name, node->id, node);
        indent++;

        for( int i=0; i<node->num_entries; i++ )
        {
            struct inode* child = (struct inode*)node->entries[i];
            printf("Child: %p\n", child);
            debug_fs( child );
        }
        indent--;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s (id %d size %db blocks ", node->name, node->id, node->filesize );
        for( int i=0; i<node->num_entries; i++ )
        {
            printf("%d ", (int)node->entries[i]);
        }
        printf(")\n");
    }
}
```

The relevant part of load_fs.c looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    printf("===================================\n");
    printf("= Load all inodes from the file   =\n");
    printf("= master_file_table               =\n");
    printf("===================================\n");
    struct inode* root = load_inodes();
    debug_fs( root );
    debug_disk();
```

Ouput after running load_fs with valgrind:

```
    ===================================
= Load all inodes from the file   =
= master_file_table               =
===================================
Start of load_inodes()NUM_INODES * sizeof: 160

ja
Before mainloop
ID: 0
Namelength: 2
Name: /
Is_directory: 1
Is_readonly: 0
Filesize: 0
Num_entries: 2
Entries: 1

ID: 1
Namelength: 7
Name: kernel
Is_directory: 0
Is_readonly: 1
Filesize: 20000
Num_entries: 5
Entries: 0

ID: 2
Namelength: 4
Name: etc
Is_directory: 1
Is_readonly: 0
Filesize: 0
Num_entries: 1
Entries: 3

ID: 3
Namelength: 6
Name: hosts
Is_directory: 0
Is_readonly: 1
Filesize: 200
Num_entries: 1
Entries: 5

Address: 0x55a9e70  Name: /
Address: 0x55a9f10  Name: kernel
Address: 0x55a9fd0  Name: etc
Address: 0x55aa070  Name: hosts
Name: / Address: 0x1ffefff5c8
/ (id 0) (address: 0x558f6b0
Child: 0x1
==3689174== Invalid read of size 8
==3689174==    at 0x4017E3: debug_fs (inode.c:298)
==3689174==    by 0x4018BA: debug_fs (inode.c:311)
==3689174==    by 0x40199D: main (load_fs.c:13)
==3689174==  Address 0x9 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==3689174==
==3689174==
==3689174== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==3689174==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x9
==3689174==    at 0x4017E3: debug_fs (inode.c:298)
==3689174==    by 0x4018BA: debug_fs (inode.c:311)
==3689174==    by 0x40199D: main (load_fs.c:13)
==3689174==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==3689174==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==3689174==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==3689174==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==3689174==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==3689174==
==3689174== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3689174==     in use at exit: 101,279 bytes in 10 blocks
==3689174==   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 2 frees, 109,959 bytes allocated
==3689174==
==3689174== 23 bytes in 4 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 4
==3689174==    at 0x4C37135: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:381)
==3689174==    by 0x4013B9: load_inodes (inode.c:163)
==3689174==    by 0x40198D: main (load_fs.c:12)
==3689174==
==3689174== 72 bytes in 4 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 4
==3689174==    at 0x4C37135: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:381)
==3689174==    by 0x4015ED: load_inodes (inode.c:197)
==3689174==    by 0x40198D: main (load_fs.c:12)
==3689174==
==3689174== 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 4
==3689174==    at 0x4C37135: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:381)
==3689174==    by 0x52500FF: _IO_file_doallocate (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so)
==3689174==    by 0x525E06F: _IO_doallocbuf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so)
==3689174==    by 0x525D2D7: _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so)
==3689174==    by 0x525C47E: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so)
==3689174==    by 0x5252542: puts (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.28.so)
==3689174==    by 0x401965: main (load_fs.c:8)
==3689174==
==3689174== 100,160 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 4
==3689174==    at 0x4C37135: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:381)
==3689174==    by 0x4012C3: load_inodes (inode.c:141)
==3689174==    by 0x40198D: main (load_fs.c:12)
==3689174==
==3689174== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3689174==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3689174==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3689174==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3689174==    still reachable: 101,279 bytes in 10 blocks
==3689174==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3689174==
==3689174== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==3689174== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
make: *** [makefile:51: valgrind_load1] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is NUM_INODES (4?)? What is `struct inode`?  Why do you add 100000 to the size (use a symbolic constant).  The size you allocate and the size you print are two different values (don't repeat yourself).  Don't cast void * from `malloc()`.  Prefer using a variable rather than type to sizeof.  Give us a program that you compiled, not a bunch of snippets to put together.  If num_entries allocation fails you leak the memory you allocated for `name`.

Comment: `xxd -r <<EOF > master_file_table <paste hexdump> EOF` to get the binary file.

Answer (score 0):

It segfaults for me in the recursive `debug_fs()` call in the first print statement with `child == 0x00` and once you move the NULL check before use `child == 0x01`:

```
    printf("Name: %s Address: %p\n", node->name, &node);
    if( node == NULL ) return;
```

The corresponds to the value at address `00000020` and `00000022` respectively which are the two `entries` for the first `inode`.

In `load_entries()` you read an array of `uintptr_t` values with `fread(entries, sizeof(uintptr_t), num_entries, f);` but in `debug_fs()` you expect entries to be an array of `struct` inode *`.  You probably want those entries to be a index into node:

```
            struct inode* child = &node[node->entries[i]];
```

After this change your code no longer segfaults:

```
Name: / Address: 0x7fff466edde0
/ (id 0) (address: 0x5651e2c4e480
Child: 0x5651e2c4e4a8
Name: kernel Address: 0x7fff466edda0
  kernel (id 1 size 20000b blocks 0 1 2 3 4 )
Child: 0x5651e2c4e4d0
Name: etc Address: 0x7fff466edda0
  etc (id 2) (address: 0x5651e2c4e4d0
Child: 0x5651e2c4e548
Name: (null) Address: 0x7fff466edd60
    (null) (id 0 size 0b blocks )
```

Couple of other suggestions:

1. Write a `free_inodes()` and use that in if `malloc()` fails in `load_indoes()`.  This means you want to ensure that all i->name and i->entries are NULL after the current location in the array.  The easiest way to do that is use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`:

```
void free_inodes(struct inode *inodes) {
    for(struct inode *i = inodes; i < inodes + NUM_INODES; i++) {
        free(i->name);
        free(i->entries);
    }
    free(inodes);
}
```

2. You might want to change the interface for `load_entries()` so it can tell you how many inodes were in the file (instead of hard-coding `NUM_INODES`).